# How to make this NodeJS package browser compatible?

Tags: node.js, typescript, bower

I built my last pet project on top of nodejs. I chose this technology because I didn't have any previous experience with it and I was curious about it.

Now I want to know what should I change in this package in order to be able to run in a browser and latter publish it to Bower.

I built [this npm package](https://github.com/minduca/gecko-ci/). Here's its structure :

- It does not have any external dependencies
- There are many small modules in separate files (see src folder). All these modules are loaded via CommonJS `require` syntax.
- There are some `require("http")` and `require("url")`.
- I don't use any specific ressource of the machine that runs it. It could be theorically used as a front-end package.

What are the minimum changes that I could do in order to have this project browser compatible?

---

**EDIT**

I replaced "Bower" by "Browser", because my problem was not about how to publish a package to Bower, but what are the minimum changes that I can do in order to have this node package able to run in a browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found my answer here :

- [How to Make Simple Node.js Modules Work in the Browser](http://www.richardrodger.com/2013/09/27/how-to-make-simple-node-js-modules-work-in-the-browser/#.WDMU-GczVHE)
- [Writing for node and the browser](https://caolan.org/posts/writing_for_node_and_the_browser.html)

Answer (score 1):

Minimum requirement is a **bower.json** in specific format. Check this [link](https://github.com/bower/spec/blob/master/json.md.) to know about the format.

To publish follow the steps mentioned in this [link](https://bower.io/docs/creating-packages/).

Let me know if you need nay help.